# How to fix FileNotFoundExceptionEntry fileTemplates//code/Google Test Fixture SetUp Method.cc.ft in Android Studio on Mac?

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio

I create a default project on Android Studio 2.1 on Mac and when I try to build, I get the following error:

`FileNotFoundException: Entry fileTemplates//code/Google Test Fixture SetUp Method.cc.ft not found in /Applications/Android%20Studio.app/Contents/lib/idea.jar`

Someone know how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe this: http://fxcode121.blogspot.com.br/2015/07/filenotfoundexception-exception-in.html ?

Comment: This didn't work for me. My notebook is 64 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the last version of Android Studio.